# HttpPost in MVC 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-net-mvc-1

I have to maintain a project that uses MVC 1. It seems like it doesn't know anything about `[HttpPost]`, and the same action method is called for both get and post. What is the right way to distinguish between creating a view and submitting the form data?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [post and get with same method signature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724386/post-and-get-with-same-method-signature)

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. I did not try to use the same signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC 1 is ancient but in order to do that you use the AcceptVerbs attribute

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

or

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
```

etc.

Comment: So the full solution can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724386/post-and-get-with-same-method-signature The AcceptVerbs gives you HttpPost/Get but you also need to have the additional signature changes.

Comment: Never mind, I needed to specify method="post" on the form. Thanks.