# Why are GET and POST requests going to the same method labeled with [HttpGet]?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, routes

In my MVC controller, I have two methods with the same action name but with different routing attributes so they respond differently to GET and POST requests (modeled by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724386/post-and-get-with-same-method-signature)):

```
[HttpGet]
public string Test()
{
    return "get";
}

[ActionName("Test")]
[HttpPost]
public string Test_Post()
{
    return "post";
}
```

and the corresponding URI is just `Sample/Test`. I've also enabled attribute routing with `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in my RouteConfig.cs.

However, if I send a GET or POST request to this URI, it always calls `Test()`, never `Test_Post()`. Why are the requests routed to the same method and ignoring the route attributes?

EDIT: To clarify, I send the request with an AJAX call:

```
$.post("https://{baseURL}/Sample/Test", function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }});
```

which always prints "get" via `Test()` instead of "post" via `Test_Post()`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Turns out I was using the System.Web.Http namespace in my MVC controller, but the ActionName, AcceptVerbs, etc. attributes exist in both the Http and Mvc namespaces. I explicitly referenced the System.Web.Mvc namespace and the attributes work fine now.